# Getting environment context in .NET plugin for Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, odata, webapi

I am currently developing a plugin for my Dynamics 365 environment. Its purpose is to handle data and pass it to a custom component. I have figured out how to get the environment context in the custom component (using power app component framework), however I am struggling to figure out how to do it in a .NET plugin.

What I am hoping to do is make Odata or fetchXML calls without needing to hard code the url. What I mean by this is not having `https://{myorg}.crm6.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/` in the code and just supplying the entity and call parameters. For example providing `lead?$select=address1_county,leadid`, so that it can work with any Dynamics environment.

The Power Apps Component Framework uses:

```
private _context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>;

public init(context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>, notifyOutputChanged: () => void, state: ComponentFramework.Dictionary, container: HTMLDivElement): void {
    this._context = context;
    this._context.webAPI.retieveMultipleRecords("lead", "?$select=address1_county,leadid").then((lead)=>{
       //Do whatever with data
    })
}
```

Whereas, I can't find a way of achieving the same results with the .NET plugin.